# Choose most recent date in a dataframe

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have the following dataframe

```
data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(19052, 19083, 19113, 19144, 
19174, 19205, 19236, 19266, 19297, 19327, 19358, 19389, 19417, 
19052, 19083, 19113, 19144, 19174, 19205, 19236, 19266, 19297, 
19327, 19052, 19083, 19113, 19144, 19174, 19205, 19236, 19266, 
19297, 19327, 19052, 19083, 19113, 19144, 19174, 19205, 19236, 
19052, 19083, 19113, 19144, 19174, 19205, 19236, 19052, 19083, 
19113, 19144, 19174, 19205, 19236, 19052, 19083, 19113, 19144, 
19174, 19205, 19236, 19052, 19083, 19113, 19144, 19174, 19205, 
19236, 19052, 19083, 19113, 19144, 19174, 19205, 19236, 19052, 
19083, 19113, 19144, 19174, 19205, 19236), class = "Date"), Variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L), levels = c("Home Loan Rate (Inverse*)", "Individual Mortgage Credit Growth (Annual)", 
"Corporate Mortgage Credit Growth (Annual)", "House Price Growth (Annual)", 
"House Sales Growth (Annual)", "Land Servicing Growth (Annual)", 
"Rental Price Growth (Annual)", "Rental Yield (Annualised)", 
"Price to Rent Ratio (Inverse*)", "Deposit to Rent Ratio (Inverse*)"
), class = "factor"), Value = c(1.07330286955238, 0.868031331627145, 
0.838967514517929, 0.463265282901492, 0.440774664858868, -0.114920479113654, 
-0.131209191309587, -0.690282254451901, -0.700262583408492, -1.07044544688435, 
-1.07044544688435, -1.2479133397482, -1.24037285713795, -1.61815254339163, 
-1.65860455570738, -1.69450715749862, -1.75235427393505, -1.77759594362444, 
-1.81421506347051, -1.82772798251858, -1.77605994837364, -1.74797490635011, 
-1.67248718427312, -0.489731665372309, -0.375786260874137, -0.273147118041471, 
-0.219280760515418, -0.118465483896136, -0.104682476320459, -0.163101080383777, 
-0.294863401778571, -0.434319522718912, -0.566434667377509, 0.629683619908471, 
0.264873886560817, -0.329513593756209, -0.858673495124316, -1.10343229300746, 
-1.14259262795293, -1.06861192593692, -0.981084076119023, -1.31317730018669, 
-1.63187286108727, -1.46785913909121, -1.29595081842591, -1.2351692864199, 
-1.20184459510015, -2.06450868260447, -1.9043853945809, -1.71523173131239, 
-1.49753473816984, -1.3860409166767, -1.30267643379579, -1.17742496935944, 
0.30180670039947, 0.0188756825732555, -0.0959248501495491, 0.00814692851823226, 
0.0645352688867332, 0.204012447437631, 0.355076984876395, -1.79182327368056, 
-1.81405242562308, -1.78335317729538, -1.87500608408319, -1.71769883015174, 
-1.64523958217052, -1.64559888051315, -1.91385948260632, -1.99379412116874, 
-2.06450492960447, -2.03968561626692, -1.79481179011783, -1.69716498079609, 
-1.71135399449119, 1.52168949467607, 1.49924004089667, 1.46982847184205, 
1.44561864874365, 1.40748455375015, 1.36246883560336, 1.31707052558479
), Color = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("#0a5d00", "#0eff00", 
"#ece75f", "#FFBF00", "#ff0000", "#7b0000"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), Label = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("> 2 Standard Deviations from mean", 
"1 to 2 Standard Deviations from mean", "0 to 1 Standard Deviations from mean", 
"0 to -1 Standard Deviations from mean", "-1 to -2 Standard Deviations from mean", 
"> -2 Standard Deviations from mean"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
))), row.names = c(NA, -82L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I would like to extract the last/most recent date in the `Date` column, which I would usually do like this

```
tail(data$Date, 1)
[1] "2022-09-01"
```

The only issue is that the end observation for the last variable in my dataframe (`Deposit to Rent Ratio (Inverse*)`) ends in `2022-09-01`, whereas some of the other variables end as recently as `2023-03-01`. Is there a way to pull the most recent date from my dataframe in a dynamic way? (which would for example be `2023-01-01` in the `Home Loan Rate (Inverse*)` variable)

Comment: Simply using `max(data$Date)` works

Comment: To follow your existing code, sort then get the last value: `tail(sort(data$Date), 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the most recent date from your dataframe dynamically using the max() function.
Here's how you can do it:

```
most_recent_date <- max(data$Date)
```

The max() function finds the maximum value in a vector, and in this case, it will find the latest date in the Date column of your dataframe. By assigning the result to the most_recent_date variable, you will have the most recent date available in your data.

Answer (score 1):

using `dplyr`:

```
data |> 
dplyr::group_by(Variable) |> 
dplyr::summarise(max_date = max(Date))
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   Variable                                   max_date  
   <fct>                                      <date>    
 1 Home Loan Rate (Inverse*)                  2023-03-01
 2 Individual Mortgage Credit Growth (Annual) 2022-12-01
 3 Corporate Mortgage Credit Growth (Annual)  2022-12-01
 4 House Price Growth (Annual)                2022-09-01
 5 House Sales Growth (Annual)                2022-09-01
 6 Land Servicing Growth (Annual)             2022-09-01
 7 Rental Price Growth (Annual)               2022-09-01
 8 Rental Yield (Annualised)                  2022-09-01
 9 Price to Rent Ratio (Inverse*)             2022-09-01
10 Deposit to Rent Ratio (Inverse*)           2022-09-01
```

Comment: I think they just want max.

Comment: @zx8754 That would be easier but their last paragraph seems to suggest they want it per-variable.  Let's see what OP responds!

Comment: Thanks @PaulStaffordAllen, I only needed the max across the entire dataset but your solution is useful as well in case I need to apply this per variable in the future

Comment: @zx8754 looks like you were right.

Comment: Then I suggest you delete this answer. If this was an answer it would be a duplicated and it is not what OP wants.